# In Python: saving Unicode letters with newlines into a .txt so that it works fine while opening both using Excel and a text editor

Tags: python, excel, unicode

I want to save some unicode data into a .txt file, so that it looks OK while opening the same file both in text editor and using Excel.
Tried to codecs.open() the txt file using different encodings, but this "codecs" library does not show newlines, what is not OK while opening the txt file in file explorer, however when I open it in Excel I can see newlines. But I also need to see my unicode letters. I cannot manage to have both (unicode symbols and newlines) in both ways of opening the txt file..

Comment: This should only be a few lines of code to demonstrate, why don't you add them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`codecs.open()` doesn't convert `'\n'` (newline) to `os.linesep` (`'\r\n'` on Windows). You could try `io.open()` instead:

```
import io

with io.open(r'c:\path\to\output.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig') as file:
    file.write(u"abc\n")
    file.write(u"\u2744\n")
```

Comment: I think that I also need to `file.close()` at the end. Still, this worked well.

Comment: @ZygD: `with`-statement closes the file automatically (even if an error occurs)